# Single board PC for ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey

Which Single board computers are recommended/better suited for running ROS (Fuerte and Ubunutu 12.04 or other recommendation)?

This has been asked a few times before, but not recently as far as I could find anwyays, sorry if double up though.

My application will be running with a Hokuyo URG LIDAR (http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/products/urg-04lx-ug01/) and using an Arduino to do all the motor/servo controls.

All low level control such as SLAM will done on board so will need to be capable of processing everything.

It will also be sending and receiving high level information from a main computer so will need to be network capable as well, we do currently have a Wireless modem on the robot itself so the SBC does not need built in wireless.

Cheers for any advice

Henry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45950/single-board-pc-for-ros/) by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my point of view, one of the best ways to find out which SBC to use is to take a look at what other people have published regarding their experiments with ROS. As an example, in [ethzasl_ptam](http://ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_ptam) wiki page, there are some references to published works that include technical details about a working SBC based flying robot doing Visual SLAM and navigation.

From my own experience, you need a SBC with least a 1.0Ghz modern CPU + 2GB of RAM. If power consumption is not a concern, I would recommend Intel Core CPUs over Atoms.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2012-10-16**:
hey cheers

Yea been trying to find SBC that other people have used, so many of them though haha

Useful recommendation information, will keep that in mind

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2012-10-16**:
hey cheers

Yea been trying to find SBC that other people have used, so many of them though haha